# What does +XP refer to in tech descriptions of Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

What does +XP refer to in tech descriptions of Endless Space? For instance, in "Hardened Framing", its description is given as: "+6 ship XP on building on star system". Does this mean the built ship gets +6 hit points, or the hero leading the system (if there is one) would get 6 experience points for each ship built in that system? I am asking because the font is small enough on my system that the description might be "+6 ship HP on building on star system", and for close quarter slug fests at the start of the game, I could use all the edges I can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+XP bonuses on improvements give each ship built in that system a starting experience bonus. The icon on one of the top corners (can't remember which one) of the ship portrait shows the level of the ships. Experience can also be gained in combat, and through random encounters.